# Button disappears after displaying score

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having issues making a basic incremental "clicker" game
every time I click the button the button disappears but the score pops up

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/interface.css" />
        <title>Face Clicker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <span id="faces"/>
        <button id="Face" onClick="faceClick(1)"><img src="images/face.png"><p align="center" style="line-height:-200em">Click Me!</p></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var faces = 0;

function faceClick(number) {
    faces = faces + number;
    document.getElementById("faces").innerHTML = faces;
};
```

Comment: please create a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `<span id="faces"/>` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var faces = 0;

function faceClick(number) {
    faces = faces + number;
    document.getElementById("faces").innerHTML = faces;
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/interface.css" />
        <title>Face Clicker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <span id="faces"> </span>
        <button id="Face" onClick="faceClick(1)"><img src="images/face.png"><p align="center" style="line-height:-200em">Click Me!</p></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fixed.
You forgot to close `<span>`.
Your `<span />` doesn't close that way. You need to close span like this `<span></span>`

Comment: Thanks, easier than i thought

Comment: @JujharSingh OK, but do you also realise what went wrong? _Why_ the button disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span id="faces"><span/>
```

instead of:

```
<span id="faces"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was you were declaring

```
   <span id="faces" />
```

But you have to declare it as

```
   <span id="faces"></span>
```

span tag was not closing properly

```js
var faces = 0;

function faceClick(number) {
  //alert(number);
    faces = faces + number;
    document.getElementById("faces").innerHTML = faces;
};
debugger
```

```html
<span id="faces"></span>
        <button id="Face" onClick="faceClick(1)"><img src="images/face.png"><p align="center" style="line-height:-200em">Click Me!</p></button>
```

Hope it help